# field autocomplete with the same value of another field

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

i have a problem and i don't know if drupal has support for it. for example I have "field one" and "field two" and i want that when in content type an user select a value in "field one", "field two" fills with the value selected in the "field one". It's posible to achieve that? Tried a lot of modules like autofill, or dependency control but seems that don't work in my case. Thanks!!!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to store the same value in two different fields?

Comment: Because i hace a taxonomy term field with stored data and a list that is form drupalgap and only the lists works un drupalgap

Comment: Anyone can help me???

Comment: If you want the user to see this happening on the front-end, then you will have to write some custom Javascript. Something like: When field one changes, assign the value of field one to field two.

Comment: If you don't want the end-user to see this, then you will have to do some code in a custom module.  You need to intercept the editing process some time before the node is saved, and copy the value of field one to field two.

Comment: finally i did it editing code in sublime text 2, i copied one database value created manually and replicated in all the term ids. Hope this helps someone.